# I`m stuck with back propagation during transposed convolution layer

Tags: conv-neural-network, transpose, backpropagation

I have a problem. Im writting my own GAN where used Trasposed Convolution Layer
With Transposed Convolution and with forward feed i don`t have any problems, but with back propagation..

Problem leads in difference between convolution and trasposed convolution:

```
public Tensor BackPropagate(Tensor error, double learningRate, bool backPropagate) {
        var inputTensor = Input;
        var extendedError = error.GetSameChannels(inputTensor);
        
        var originalFilters = new Filter[Filters.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < Filters.Length; i++)
            originalFilters[i] = new Filter(new List<Matrix>(Filters[i].Channels));

        if (backPropagate)
            Parallel.For(0, Filters.Length, filter => {
                for (var channel = 0; channel < Filters[filter].Channels.Count; channel++){
                    Filters[filter].Channels[channel] -= Convolution.GetConvolution(
                         error.Channels[filter], extendedInput.Channels[filter],
                        _stride, Filters[filter].Bias) * learningRate;
                }

                Filters[filter].Bias -= error.Channels[filter].Sum() * learningRate;
            });
        
        return Convolution.GetConvolution(extendedError, 
            FlipFilters(GetFiltersWithoutBiases(originalFilters)), _stride);
    }
```

During Forward pass, as example, i get from 4x4x9 tensor 18x18x6 tensor. But during back propagation, when i try to calculate grad for filter by convolving error with input, i get dirrente with filter shape (i know that is normal cuz a formula for conv and transposed conv diffent). But i dont know any anotwer way to calculate grad for filter in trasposed convolution layer.

How to solve this problem?
Please help me :(